# How to make a PDF file with text being like images?

Tags: pdf

I don't want the text in the file to be recognised as text but as images because I want to avoid any errors when opening the pdf file on different systems and devices. How can I do that? and how can I convert a regular PDF file to a PDF file as described above.

Comment: take screenshot of each page and then save the pages as one single PDF file using any PDF creation software

Comment: *"I want to avoid any errors when opening the pdf file on different systems and devices"* Like what? Using images will surely make zooming (in *and* out, like for small devices) result in hard to read text.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why there could appear any errors with text when opening a PDF document on another system, because PDF is known for keeping it's formatting very well even across systems, but if you really want to not save your text as text in the PDF, then I would recommend converting the text to paths in your PDF. This will mean that instead of the characters, the exact outline of the letters is saved in your PDF. But, as an advantage to saving the text as images, it keeps being vector, so you can still zoom in the PDF with nice and sharp text output (no pixels, no smudge), and images would really increase your file size into the overkill, whereas saving vectors doesn't.

Usually, you archieve this when using a professional print or design application (like Adobe InDesign or Illustrator, or most of the equivalents), because they include a "convert text to paths"-option, but if you don't own these applications, here's a little trick to do this in Acrobat:

1. Open the PDF in Acrobat
2. Go to Tools > Watermark > Add Watermark
3. Enter any watermark in the watermark window (this is not relevant, because we don't want a watermark, it's just to trick Adobe), *but* make sure to change it's opacity to zero, so anyone opening your PDF doesn't get annoyed
4. If a little watermark on your PDF isn't too bad, you could still use this as a feature
5. Save the watermark by clicking "OK"
6. Go to Tools > Print Production > Flattener Preview
7. In this dialog, there's a box that's called "convert all text to outlines". This is actually what we need
8. Check this box, and hit apply (You *must* hit apply, only clicking "OK" doesn't do the trick)
9. Save your modified PDF, probably under a different filename, and enjoy your text converted to outlines ;)

[Source](http://www.startscreenprintingnow.com/convertfonts/)

Comment: Thanks for this trick. I don't have Acrobat now on my mac, but I will try it. The reason I want this is that if I use some font that is not popular in my PDF file, will it be displayed without errors on some device that doesn't have this font installed??

Comment: Fonts (more precise: the used characters) are included in the PDF, if all is well, @ammarx.

Comment: @ammarx: Guess what, PDF is self-contained, and it will contain the glyphs of the fonts it needs (this is called embedding and subsetting a font). So, if following best practices when creating the PDF, there are no font issues (well, there may be, if the font creator does not allow embedding; in this case change font or font creator). Also note that rendering outlines of fonts gives different results than rendering fonts, especially with little zoom factors.

Comment: @MaxWyss , thanks. Is there a way to know if a font allows embedding or not ?

Comment: @ammarx: The easiest way to find out is creating a simple form in Acrobat and then select that particular font. If Acrobat refuses to use that font, it can not be fully embedded. The next step would be creating a sample document with settings that do embed (and subset) the font. If it passes, your font can be embedded and subsetted. A more technical approach would be analysing the font file; depending on the font type, there are rights flags, which you can read out; where the flags are located can be found in the respective font specifications.

Comment: @ammarx: Note that PostScript Type 1 fonts do not have the rights flags, and therefore can always be embedded (and subsetted).

Comment: @ammarx You're welcome ;) As I mentioned in my post, and as the others said here, PDF usually contains all the resources it needs for proper display, unless there are license restrictions preventing this. So you really shouldn't need to force-embed your fonts, just try it out by creating a PDF with the font you want to use, transfer that PDF to a machine where the font is not installed (your phone, a friend's computer), and check if it displays right. If it does, the font was embedded in the PDF and there's no need to worry about emedding it manually, it will work on any computer.